# feature engineering mechanism

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering, gradient-descent, feature-scaling, efficiency

why do we need to rescale some  feature having large range I know  we do it for faster rate of gradient descent ,but still how does rescaling works? and it doesn't break the model
and does rescaling just decreases the time or it even improves the accuracy of the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand that, we have to look into models:

- Not all models needs scaling. Only linear models needs scaling. Like Linear regression, Logistic regression or NN.
- It's because they have certain criteria to fulfill to get good results. For example, For linear regression to work well, the data needs to be linearly separable. On the other hand, the models like Decision tree or RandomForest or Boosting models doesn't need data to be scaled because at core they are using trees to understand the data.
- So to conclude, I can say that, it does improve the speed, but it is also helpful for model to understand the model better.
  Tip: To know about the linear models and their requirements, do some basic research and you will find out about the rules.